# How to invoke middleware only when the app is started, not for every request in .net core api?

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, middleware

I have written a middle ware which will download some files from git. But I want to restrict the middleware invocation to **only once** when the app is started. So the files should be downloaded only when the app is started,not with every request.
**NOTE- The middleware is part of a custom nuget package which will be reused by many services to download file in startup, not for a particular service**

Please see the code snippets for reference.
TIA

````
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseTlsEnableMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env, OracleTlsConfigurations oraTlsConfigurations)
        {
            return app.UseMiddleware<OracleTlsMiddleware>(env, oraTlsConfigurations);
        }
    }


public class OracleTlsMiddleware
    {
        RequestDelegate _next;
        public OracleTlsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostEnvironment env, OracleTlsConfigurations oraTlsConfigurations)
        {
            _next = next;
            if (oraTlsConfigurations != null)
            {
                _oraTlsConfigurations = oraTlsConfigurations;
                _env = env;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Oracle Tls Configurations not found in cofig file");
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
                //some work to download file
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception occured while donloading oracle TLS files: {ex.Message}");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            var oracleTlsConfig = Configuration.GetSection("OracleTlsConfigurations").Get<OracleTlsConfigurations>();
            app.UseTlsEnableMiddleware(env, oracleTlsConfig);

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json", "Sales Order Details");
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Please share a [mcve] (code **in the question**).

Comment: Do you make use of the 'context' object passed as a parameter in InvokeAsync method?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad, can you please give some example? that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid the custom middleware component might not work as intended, because the middleware component gets inserted into the asp.net pipe line and gets called on every request. If the whole purpose of the custom compoent is to just download files, you can write it as a normal class and call it directly in Startup.cs

```
public class OracleTlsMiddleware
{
    public OracleTlsMiddleware(IHostEnvironment env, OracleTlsConfigurations oraTlsConfigurations)
    {
        if (oraTlsConfigurations != null)
        {
            _oraTlsConfigurations = oraTlsConfigurations;
            _env = env;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Oracle Tls Configurations not found in cofig file");
    }

    public void DownloadFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            //some work to download file
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception occured while donloading oracle TLS files: {ex.Message}");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    var oracleTlsConfig = Configuration.GetSection("OracleTlsConfigurations").Get<OracleTlsConfigurations>();
    var useTlsEnableMiddleware = new UseTlsEnableMiddleware(env, oracleTlsConfig);
    useTlsEnableMiddleware.DownloadFiles();
}
```

I have not changed the name of class for the sake of understanding. You can give in a more meaningingful name based upon the context.

Answer (score 1):

For solve this you don't need to make the middleware. Just to write a method and execute it in your startup.cs.

Comment: I have edited my post.. the middleware is common to all services (part of a custom nuget),  not specific to one service.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  Ultimately you (the OP) is asking "how to I make middleware not act like middleware" which means the original implementation is errant.